# PM2 keep spamming terminals on start

Tags: node.js, pm2

I have created pm2 Ecosystem File that looks like this:

```js
const os = require('os');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

const services = [ 
        {name: 'gatewayService', port: 3000}, 
        {name: 'microserviceA', port: 3001},
        {name: 'microserviceB', port: 3002}
];

const backend = services.map(service => ({
                script: 'src/index.ts',
                node_args: ' -r ts-node/register',
                interpreter: 'node'm
                max_restarts: 10,
                detached: true,
                name: service.name,
                watch: ['src'],
                cwd: `../${service.name}`,
                env :{
                        port: service.port, 
                        ...otherEnvs
                }
        }));

module.exports = {
  apps: backend
};
```

In the CMD I run `pm2 run ./ecosystemFile.js`.

For some reason that I can't figure out way, it keeps spamming on start with terminals (i figured out it's the node process).
I don't know why but even the max_restart policy is being ignored.

Searched for few days but nothing seems to work.

Specs: Windows 11, node 16.16.0, pm2-latest - running on fork mode.

Thanks.